# Why are some Unicode characters displayed incorrectly on iOS?

Tags: ios, unicode, character

The [CURLY LOGICAL AND (U+22CF)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22cf/index.htm) and [CURLY LOGICAL OR (U+22CE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22ce/index.htm) are not displayed correctly on iOS. It seems to swap the presentation of the two characters.

The below line consists of the Logical And and the Logical Or respectively. You should see an upside-down v before a v but if you are on an iOS device, you will see the v before the upside-down v.

`⋏` `⋎`

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

EDIT: I tested on iOS 9.3.2.

EDIT 2: This is apparently not a problem with the system font of iOS 9.3.2. I tried displaying those characters on Mac using the SanFrancisco font and they were still displayed correctly.

EDIT 3: This occurs on iOS 10.0.1 as well.

Comment: You might need to use `NSASCIIStringEncoding` or, `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Comment: This is system-wide, not just specifically on my app. You can try viewing this page on iOS's safari to see. @iphonic